# How to create dynamic table in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to create a dynamic table.My problem is this that I want to use check boxes and buttons in row of table and the buttons and checkbox are custom one.I have created those using selector.xml files.And I am not getting how can I create and add my rows  dynamically to my TableLayout.Plz Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

[Here.](http://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/how-to-use-dynamic-tablelayout-instead-of-using-listview-in-android/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.